# Uniqueness of solution for boundary value problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, problem-solving

In the article : "Third order semipositone boundary value problems"
[image]

They assume that $w(t)$ is nondecreasing and $w(t)>0$ on $(q,1]$ .

and they found the Green's  function $$G(t,s)=-t(p-s)\chi_{[0,p]}(s)+\frac{(t-s)^2}{2} \chi_{[0,t]}(s)+\frac{t(2p-1)}{2}W(s)\chi_{[q,1]}(s)+\frac{t(2p-t)}{2}\chi_{[0,q]}(s)$$

Where $$W(s)=(\int_0^1 w(v)dv)^{-1}\int w(v) dv, s\in [q,1]$$

we have that $G(t,s)>0 $ for $t,s \in (0,1)$

And what i dont unserstand is this :

> For the function $e(t)$ given in Eq (1.1), define $$\gamma(t)=\int_0^1
>  G(t,s)e(s) ds, t\in [0,1]$$
>
> Since $e\in L(0,1)$, we have that $\gamma \in C^2[0,1]\cap C^3(0,1)$
>   and moreover ***$\gamma(t)$ is the unique solution of the BVP consisting
>    of the equation*** $$u'''=e(t), t\in (0,1)$$ and BC(1.2)